# Advanced formatting with argument passing

Tags: python, serialization

I want to customise how my objects are printed using the `.format()` function.

I have two problems to make that happen in clear and concise way. But since the second one stems from the first one I'm presenting both here.

**Formatting array**

Passing options to `.format()` in array seems to me to be awfully messy if I want to match default behaviour with `__repr__`:

```
import binascii


def format_data(data, formatstr):
    if 'x' in formatstr:
        return binascii.b2a_hex(data).decode('ascii')
    else:
        return repr(data)


class InsideA(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "InsideA()"

    def __format__(self, _):
        return "InsideA()"


class InsideB(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __repr__(self):
        data = format_data(self.data, 'x')
        return "InsideB(data={0})".format(data)

    def __format__(self, formatstr):
        data = format_data(self.data, formatstr)
        return "InsideB(data={0})".format(data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = InsideA()
    b = InsideB(bytearray(b'test\xff\xff'))

    array = [a, b]

    print("what I want:")
    print(array)
    print("")

    print("doesn't work:")
    try:
        print("{0:x}".format(array))
    except Exception as e:  # catch just to continue execution
        print(e)
    print("")

    print("Leaves ' around elements:")
    print(["{0:x}".format(elem) for elem in array])
    print("")

    print("Works but seems overly complex:")
    print("[" + ", ".join("{0:x}".format(elem) for elem in array) + "]")
```

Produces:

What I want:

> ```
> [InsideA(), InsideB(data=74657374ffff)]
> ```

Doesn't work:

> ```
> non-empty format string passed to object.__format__
> ```

Leaves `'` around elements:

> ```
> ['InsideA()', 'InsideB(data=74657374ffff)']
> ```

Works but seems overly complex:

> ```
> [InsideA(), InsideB(data=74657374ffff)]
> ```

**Formatting with non-uniform objects**

The problem only gets compounded if the array elements don't always implement the format function, requiring use of `try` `except` clauses:

```python
from __future__ import print_function
import binascii


def format_data(data, formatstr):
    if 'x' in formatstr:
        return binascii.b2a_hex(data).decode('ascii')
    else:
        return repr(data)


class InsideA(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "InsideA()"


class InsideB(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __repr__(self):
        data = format_data(self.data, 'x')
        return "InsideB(data={0})".format(data)

    def __format__(self, formatstr):
        data = format_data(self.data, formatstr)
        return "InsideB(data={0})".format(data)

def format_array(array, formatstr):
    if array is None:
        return "None"
    else:
        str_array = []
        for elem in array:
            try:
                str_array += ["{0:{1}}".format(elem, formatstr)]
            except (TypeError, ValueError):  # Py2 and Py3 compat
                str_array += [repr(elem)]
        return "[" + ", ".join(str_array) + "]"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = InsideA()
    b = InsideB(bytearray(b'test\xff\xff'))

    array = [a, b]

    print("Automatic:")
    print(array)
    print("")


    print("With format:")
    print(format_array(array, "x"))
```

Prints:

Automatic:

> ```
> [InsideA(), InsideB(data=74657374ffff)]
> ```

With format:

> ```
> [InsideA(), InsideB(data=74657374ffff)]
> ```

This code in `format_array()` seems to me to be too complex for what it does. Do I don't know of some syntax that makes this a breeze or is it the best Python can do?

(Yes, I know that I can implement `__repr__` as just a call to `format()`, leaving that in for readability of example.)

Comment: It appears that the code is not behaving the way you want it to, so this is a "How can I …?" question that should be asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @200_success: It is behaving as I want it to. I'm asking how I can make it simpler or more readable. The code definitely is not "broken" - both examples run and produce the expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stripping down my [rather longish answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/113842/78136) to the minimum you have two options as I see it:

- Implement a subclass of list with a dedicated `__format__` option
- Use a function like `format_array()`

### Refactored `format_array()`

Your `format_array()` does the work but has the following issues related to doing it the Pythonic way:

- *Explicit `if None ... else` instead of ternary* – You could use `return "list" if array else "None"`, to simplify away the if else structure
- *Remove anti-pattern of `list = []; for ...: list.append()`* – This can be replaced with a list comprehension, i.e `[something(e) for e in array]`. However to get to use it in your case we need to use an extra inner function to handle the `try .. except` clause
- *Avoid using `+` for string comprehension* – Most people like to avoid using string concatenation with pluss, and in this case you could use `'[{}]'.format( ... )`.

Compensating for these we get the following code:

```
def format_array(array, formatstr):
    """Ensure that format is called for each of the array elements."""

    def format_or_repr(elem):
        try:
            return format(elem, formatstr)
        except (TypeError, ValueError, AttributeError):
            return repr(elem)

   return '[{}]'.format(', '.join(map(format_or_repr, array))) if array else 'None'
```

Now you can do `print('{}'.format(format_array(array, "x")))`.

### Subclassing the list

Furthermore to allow for really neat print code, we could opt for subclassing the list with a specific `__format__` or `__str__` code:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __new__(cls, data=None):
        obj = super(MyList, cls).__new__(cls, data)
        return obj

    def __str__(self):
        return 'sM: MyList({})'.format(', '.join(map(str, self)))

    def __format__(self, formatstr):
        return 'fM: MyList({})'.format(format_array(self, formatstr))

    def __add__(self, other):
        return MyList(list(self) + list(other))
```

Based on code from [""Replace str method on list object in Python"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/931699/1548472). This does however require that you create your list using this class, but it does allow for a very neat syntax of `print('{:x}'.format(my_list))`.

This code still uses the `format_array()` function, but could have reimplemented it as an inner part of the function. To avoid code bloat in this bare minimum I kept it as a function call.

### Test code and output

Here is the test code:

```
def main():
    a = InsideA()
    b = InsideB(bytearray(b'test\xff\xff'))

    array = [a, b]
    my_list = MyList([a, b])

    print('plain array:           {}'.format(array))
    print('format_array:          {}'.format(format_array(array, "x")))

    print('\nUsing plain my_list:   {}'.format(my_list))
    print('Using myList and :x:   {:x}'.format(my_list))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And here is the output:

```
plain array:           [InsideA(), InsideB(data=bytearray(b'test\xff\xff'))]
format_array:          [InsideA(), InsideB(data=74657374ffff)]

Using plain my_list:   MyList([InsideA(), InsideB(data=bytearray(b'test\xff\xff'))])
Using myList and :x:   MyList([InsideA(), InsideB(data=74657374ffff)])
```

You could of course opt to not include the `MyList(...)` in the returned text of the subclassing options.

Comment: _Nice_, I knew that it was possible with list comprehension or iterators in `format_array()`. Though I will probably use `maping = (format_or_repr(i) for i in array)` instead of the `map()`.

Answer (score 3):

`list` [always uses `repr` on it's elements](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c6880edaf6f3/Objects/listobject.c#l382).
When you `str` or `repr` it.
And internally `list` is doing roughly the equivalent of what you are doing in `format_array`.

The only way to make this work is to use something like `format_array`,
or subclass `list`.
But they will both be doing the same thing, just depends on how much sugar you want.

---

Your code is nice, readable and follows PEP8.
As this is tending towards example code, it's not in it's native environment, it's hard to comment distinctively on it.

But `format_data` can be merged with the class.

```
class InsideB(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __repr__(self):
        data = self._data(True)
        return "InsideB(data={0})".format(data)

    def __format__(self, formatstr):
        data = self._data('x' in formatstr)
        return "InsideB(data={0})".format(data)

    def _data(self, as_hex):
        if as_hex:
            return binascii.b2a_hex(self.data).decode('ascii')
        else:
            return repr(self.data)
```

You can then add an option to use 'hex' or `repr` as the output type to the class.
With the option to reverting to the original after a use.
Obviously it depends on your usage.

```
class InsideB(object):
    def __init__(self, data, as_hex=False, revert_hex=False):
        self.data = data
        self._as_hex = as_hex
        self.output_type = as_hex
        self._revert_hex = revert_hex

    def _data(self, as_hex):
        if as_hex or self.output_type:
            data = binascii.b2a_hex(self.data).decode('ascii')
        else:
            data = repr(self.data)

        if self._revert_hex:
            self.output_type = self._as_hex

        return data
```

Then you would need to make a function that maps over all the items in the list,
changes `output_type` to what you want, and you'll be in the same position as you are now.
But with a bit more sugar.

---

If you choose to subclass list, and to use `str` in `__str__`,
then you'll get output which is just wrong.

```
>>> print('{!s}, {!s}'.format('a', 'b'))
a, b
>>> print('{!r}, {!r}'.format('a', 'b'))
'a', 'b'
```

---

No matter how I look at it you wont be able to change the output 'nicely'.
Unless you think something more robust to `map(lambda i: i.output_type = True, array)` is nice.

Bottom line you have to manually implement this, as `repr` is hard-coded.

Comment: "Bottom line you have to manually implement this," that's what I was afraid of

Comment: @HubertKario It could be worse, like ~10 line helper function isn't _that_ bad...

Answer (score 2):

There are two major point I would like for you to focus on:

- Python uses `repr` on each of the elements in a list (as Joe Wallis point out in his answer), and I will examplify this and show a way around it
- Convert to using `__str__` instead of `__format__`

> **Edit:** It turns out the question is really about how to apply multiple different formatting options on to each of the list elements. For specifics on this, see *Addendum* on end of answer.

### Convert to `__str__`

In the following code I've converted your `__format__` into a `__str__` function instead. The reason for this is to adhere better to the standards used when printing and formatting different objects automatically. This approach I hope will convince you is an easier approach than doing the `__format__` path.

I've also included the `__repr__` class, and added a prefix to both function so that we can easily see which one is used throughout the examples.

Here is the first part of the code:

```
import binascii

class InsideA(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "rA: InsideA()"

    def __str__(self):
        return "sA: InsideA()"


class InsideB(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __repr__(self):
        return "rB: InsideB(data={0!r})".format(self.data)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'sB: {}'.format(binascii.b2a_hex(self.data).decode('ascii'))
```

There is nothing magic happening here other than if you do `print(b)` it according to your example produce "sB: 74657374fff" (with my added prefix).

### Subclassing list to avoid `repr` on elements

As suggested in ["Replace **str** method on list object in Python"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/931699/1548472), one can subclass a list to get it to call the `__str__` method on each element. The accepted answer shows a version which:

> This solution works without a wrapper. And works if you join two lists by add. Any operation that modify the list itself will work as expected. Only functions that return a copy of the list like: `sorted`, `reversed` will return the native python list which is fine. `sort` and `reverse` on the other hand operate on the list itself and will keep the type.

Here is this class updated to use `str.format()`:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __new__(cls, data=None):
        obj = super(MyList, cls).__new__(cls, data)
        return obj

    def __str__(self):
        return 'sM: MyList({})'.format(', '.join(map(str, self)))

    def __add__(self, other):
        return MyList(list(self) + list(other))
```

### Example output and explanations

To display the difference of the various options, run the following code:

```
def strify(list, join_text=', ', join_brackets='[]'):
    """Returns join of str(list element) with join_txt, surrounded by join_brackets."""
    return '{}{}{}'.format(join_brackets[0],
                           join_text.join(str(elem) for elem in list),
                           join_brackets[1])

def main():
    a = InsideA()
    b = InsideB(bytearray(b'test\xff\xff'))

    array = [a, b]

    print('\n== Working directly on array ==')
    print('Just array:   {}'.format(array))
    print('[Joining]:    [{}]'.format(', '.join('{!s}'.format(elem) for elem in array)))
    print('map(str):     {}'.format(map(str, array)))
    print('[join & map]: [{}]'.format(', '.join(map(str, array))))
    print('Using !s:     {!s}'.format(array))
    print('Using !r:     {!r}'.format(array))
    print('strify():     {}'.format(strify(array)))

    print('\n== Working directly on *array ==')
    print('Using 2 !s:   {!s} and {!s}'.format(*array))
    print('Using 2 !r:   {!r} and {!r}'.format(*array))

    print('\n== Using MyList class on my_list ==')
    my_list = MyList([a, b])

    print('Just my_list: {}'.format(my_list))
    print('Using !s:     {!s}'.format(my_list))
    print('Using !r:     {!r}'.format(my_list))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Which produces this output:

```
== Working directly on array ==
Just array:   [rA: InsideA(), rB: InsideB(data=bytearray(b'test\xff\xff'))]
[Joining]:    [sA: InsideA(), sB: InsideB(data=74657374ffff)]
map(str):     ['sA: InsideA()', 'sB: InsideB(data=74657374ffff)']
[join & map]: [sA: InsideA(), sB: InsideB(data=74657374ffff)]
Using !s:     [rA: InsideA(), rB: InsideB(data=bytearray(b'test\xff\xff'))]
Using !r:     [rA: InsideA(), rB: InsideB(data=bytearray(b'test\xff\xff'))]
strify():     [sA: InsideA(), sB: InsideB(data=74657374ffff)]

== Working directly on *array ==
Using 2 !s:   sA: InsideA() and sB: InsideB(data=74657374ffff)
Using 2 !r:   rA: InsideA() and rB: InsideB(data=bytearray(b'test\xff\xff'))

== Using MyList class on my_list ==
Just my_list: sM: MyList(sA: InsideA(), sB: InsideB(data=74657374ffff))
Using !s:     sM: MyList(sA: InsideA(), sB: InsideB(data=74657374ffff))
Using !r:     [rA: InsideA(), rB: InsideB(data=bytearray(b'test\xff\xff'))]
```

As can be seen if you call `print(array)` it clearly uses repr on each of the elements, which you don't want. And specifying the conversion by `!s` or `!r` doesn't help either, as that only applies to the list it self and not the specific element.

However if you loop on the elements, and specify `!s` we get the wanted output. Next step would then be to do `map` but that introduces the quotes again. Combining `map` and `join` gets correct output, but the code isn't nice anymore, so then we can just as well create a function for it, aka `strify()` as given in above `main()` (or a variant of the original `format.

An alternative to get the wanted output is to specify a formatting options for each element in the array, and then use `*array`. This has the obvious downside that you need to know how many elements you have and specify each of them in the format string. Not good!  However you could force the `str` on each of the elements using `map(str, array)` which is possibly the nicest and easiest approach.

Lastly, you could use the subclassing of list with the caveats given above regarding `sorted` and `reversed` which would revert to native Python lists, and thusly using repr. But if using the `MyList` for creation, and it's not modified back to a native list, you get the proper variant when using `!s` and `!r` and you do the simple `print(myList)`.

### Conclusion

In both my suggested solutions I would use the `__str__` on the subclasses, as this helps when printing single elements as well as when used in the various other solutions.

As Python by default uses repr on each of the elements when printing a list, your best option is either to use a subclassed list which calls the `str` on each element, or to have shorter and clean code use a dedicated function like `strify`, which in the end defaults to joining str'ified version of each element.

### Addendum: To allow for multiple various format options

It turns out, see comments, that OP wants to have an option to vary the output of the formatting for each element, and then it could be viable to use the `__format__` option. In that case I would simplify the `format_array()` to the following:

```
def format_array(array, formatstr, join_text=', ', join_brackets='[]'):
    """Ensure that format is called for each of the array elements."""

    def format_or_repr(elem):
        try:
            return format(elem, formatstr)
        except (TypeError, ValueError, AttributeError):
            return repr(elem)

    return '{}{}{}'.format(join_brackets[0],
                           join_text.join(format_or_repr(elem) for elem in array),
                           join_brackets[1]) if array else 'None'

#    return '[{}]'.format(', '.join(format_or_repr(e) for e in array)) if array else 'None'
```

The commented version at bottom, is if one don't want to have the default parameters of `join_text` and `join_brackets`. The gist of the simplification is simply to use a helper function to avoid exception handling, and a `join(...) if array else 'None'` to compress the situation if function is called without a list.

Now you can use your original `format_data` and it will still default nicely to using `repr` on those not having implemented the `__format__` method.

Another version of the same using `join` and `map`, and direct index referencing of `join_bracket` follows:

```
def format_array_v2(array, formatstr, join_text=', ', join_brackets='[]'):
    """Ensure that format is called for each of the array elements."""

    def format_or_repr(elem):
        try:
            return format(elem, formatstr)
        except (TypeError, ValueError, AttributeError):
            return repr(elem)

    return '{0[0]}{1}{0[1]}'.format(
        join_brackets, 
        join_text.join(map(format_or_repr, array))
        ) if array else 'None'

#    return '[{}]'.format(', '.join(map(format_or_repr, array))) if array else 'None'
```

And finally some test-code:

```
print("\n== Using format extension ==")
print('Just format(b, "x"):     {}'.format(format(b, "x")))
print('format_array:            {}'.format(format_array(array, "x")))
print('format_array(None):      {}'.format(format_array(None, "x")))
print('format_array_v2:         {}'.format(format_array_v2(array, "x")))
print('format_array_v2(None):   {}'.format(format_array_v2(None, "x")))
```

And corresponding output:

```
== Using format extension ==
Just format(b, "x"):     fB: InsideB(data=74657374ffff)
format_array:            [rA: InsideA(), fB: InsideB(data=74657374ffff)]
format_array(None):      None
format_array_v2:         [rA: InsideA(), fB: InsideB(data=74657374ffff)]
format_array_v2(None):   None
```

Comment: It's a impressive answer, but I *know* that array uses `repr()` on elements and that's __not the problem__ . I'm asking how to make `format_array` simpler because sometimes I need to encode `bytearray`s as hex strings and sometimes as `repr()` of `bytearray`. You can't do that with just __repr__ or __str__ you need to use `format()` parametrisation.

Comment: I was looking for more of a general solution, as while for bytearrays I have just 2 options, for ints I have 4. It's really not the problem to do `str()` or `repr()`, it's how to pass format string to array elements cleanly.

Comment: @holroy I don't mean to be rude, but isn't your addendum a more complex version of OP's code?

Comment: @JoeWallis, Depends on how you see it, I guess. It removes the test against None in explicit if's and adds a bit of functionality regarding choice of join_text and brackets. It also removes an anti-pattern of explicit list comprehension. And finally it doesn't string concatenation which many doesn't like.